# How to tune web searches to filter out old information?

Tags: c#, xna

I'm currently researching XNA and C# 3.0, and other related tech (Maya 2009) and am running into a problem I always have with fast-moving technologies: my web searches come up with a lot of outdated info and it's wasting a lot of my time. Articles about betas, or old school assignments, or abandoned projects.

In looking for tutorials or engines or toolkits, I have to open a ton of tabs up from Google then go through each one by one to see if it's still active, or when the forum post was, or whatever. I'm currently living in an area where internet is extremely slow and opening up page after page only to find the date being 3-4 years old is pretty frustrating (maybe I should disable images, hmm).

When Googling news, it's simple enough to filter by date. But for ordinary web pages, what can you do?

I realize that a large reason Stack Overflow exists is to solve this exact problem, but this site seems a lot more geared towards answering problems that need solving right now as opposed to very exploratory general research.

Are there web search services that attempt to address the problem of timeliness in addition to relevance? Is there some magic clause I can type into Google that I don't know about?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Google Advanced Search](http://www.google.com/advanced_search?as_qdr=d) there is a "Date: (how recent the page is)" option.